# How to chose specific rows in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very big excel file and i want to transfer all information from worksheet to the variant variable.

I don't need all the rows from the file, so I want to chose rows that I am interested in.

I have tried to make complex Range variable using *Union* to select rows that i am interested in.

The problem is that my program doesn't increase range if useful inormation is divided by the not wanted rows.

example:
I have got table like this:

```
123|1|1|1
123|2|2|2
456|3|3|3
123|4|4|4
```

I want rows with 123 in the first column, but then i am using *Union* function, I got only first two rows, but not the fourth.

I need:

```
123|1|1|1
123|2|2|2
123|4|4|4
```

but recieve:

```
123|1|1|1
123|2|2|2
```

Below will be a part of my code. This part is in the cycle

r - Range

WS - Worksheet

```
Set r = WS.Range("A1:A1")
```

Can somebody help me with this. I am looking for a solution for hour already.

```
If WS.Cells(i, 1).Value = "123" Then
    If r.Columns.Count() < 2 Then
        Set r = WS.Range(WS.Cells(i, 1), WS.Cells(i, 4))
    Else
        Set r = Union(r, WS.Range(WS.Cells(i, 1), WS.Cells(i, 4)))
    End If
End If
```

Comment: How about filtering the first column by the desired value? Maybe you don't need VBA for this at all. This can probably be done with Power Query in just a few clicks without writing any VBA.

Comment: This can work but isn't this slower that just pick certain rows?
It is very important to me, because I have couple big files and i want to optimize my program a much as I can.

Comment: Filtering is the way to go. You don't say how you are returning `r`. You probably need to loop through its areas as it is not contiguous.

Comment: Well, filtering it is then.
Didn't want to filter, but I guesss, this is the way to go...

Comment: As they are telling you above filtering is the way, just because filtering will be executed once, while trying to build a Range by looping a big file will take a big amount of time. Once your data is filtered you could build the Range by using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` do not attempt to pull the filtered data into a `Variant`variable because it won't work.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you

Comment: Filtering is the easier option.. not the optimal. If you have a large file, you will have to filter and unfilter.. which can be time consuming. You could just get your range in an array and then use the array to build your **"variant"**

Comment: Are you allowed to sort your data before copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, using your approach:

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set r = ws.Range("A1")

For i = 1 To 4
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = 123 Then
        If r.Columns.Count < 2 Then
            Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 4))
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 4)))
        End If
    End If
Next i

For j = 1 To r.Areas.Count
    Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(r.Areas(j).Rows.Count, r.Areas(j).Columns.Count).Value = r.Areas(j).Value
Next j

End Sub
```

[image]

---

Using an array approach, the results are stored in `v2`.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, v As Variant, v2() As Variant

v = Range("A1:D4").Value

ReDim Preserve v2(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To UBound(v, 2))

For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    If v(i, 1) = 123 Then
        j = j + 1
        v2(j, 1) = v(i, 1)
        v2(j, 2) = v(i, 2)
        v2(j, 3) = v(i, 3)
        v2(j, 4) = v(i, 4)
    End If
Next i

Range("G1").Resize(j, UBound(v2, 2)).Value = v2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. But i need to transfer information to the variable. Not in the excel file. Is there a method to do this? 
I am doing like this, but no results:
 
temp = r.Value

Comment: An array? Why not do it all via arrays then?

Comment: How to do that? 
I mean, i have tried to use ReDim Preserve, but didn't got any good results with that. (I am new to VBA, so i got a ton of problems with my code)

Comment: Edited answer above.